# Best Caching method for caching news articles for offline reading

Tags: android, caching, offline-caching

Please suggest me a caching technique where I can cache the list of items downloaded when network is on and read from cache in the absence of network. I need to have the limit for number of items stored in cache (each item avg size will be 10kb) . It will be help full if the caching technique used will handle the deleting mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're storing or how much sorting you need, but if it's simple id = article to recall the basic data I'd say just use text files. Sometime simple works.

- article121.txt
- article1441.txt
- ... etc

Alternatively, in the same vein you could use JSON files

- article121.json
- article1441.json
- ...etc

Contents of JSON could contain values for title, body, etc (if needed).

If you need to sort or search them directly I'd say SQLite probably.

Comment: What if I want to save an Html file. My webview handles the caching but I want to cache Images inside the html separately .

Comment: I would probably just use folder structures.

Create a directory called "cache" (inside of your app's files directory). Then create a directory called "article2212" then inside of that put all of your html and image files. Then just reload them when you need them.